# C++ Client networking library with JSON handler

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, libraries

I'm moving from Java and was looking for something as simple as possible to manage a client connection from C++.

In Java I used Netty, that was really straightforward. Once you opened the connection, it's very easy to convert object in JSON and send them.

Looking on SO, I have found only long list of libraries for general networking, but I was wondering if anybody already had the same specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to http://json.org/ you'll see a list of libraries in c++, and other languages to solve this. Just scroll down to the bottom.